# Bootstrap card not getting styled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am editing an old website. The website uses bootstrap 3.3.6

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Example
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul id="example">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this code, the Card dose not get styled. Is this not supported on the bootstrap 3.3.6? If yes how can I upgrade bootstrap? just change the bootstrap.min.css file? Could that broke other parts of the website?

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.6 has no card component @ssalc

Comment: please check the documentation for bootstrap very well and check the version you're using before you ask spend some times to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no card component in Bootstrap v3, its new feature in v4.

There are many breaking changes in Bootstrap v4.
Refer their website for the changes and [Migration Guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/)

For now, use the below snippet to style your cards. I copied the entire card.css from bootstrap 4.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card>hr {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.card>.list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card>.list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.card-subtitle {
  margin-top: -0.375rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-text:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-link+.card-link {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.card-header {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.card-header+.list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.card-footer:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-header-tabs {
  margin-right: -0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.75rem;
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.card-header-pills {
  margin-right: -0.625rem;
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
}

.card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-deck {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-deck {
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .card-deck .card {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

.card-group {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-group>.card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-group {
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .card-group>.card {
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card+.card {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-header {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:first-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:last-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:only-child {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:only-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-img-top,
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-header,
  .card-group>.card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-footer {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.card-columns .card {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;
  }
  .card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.accordion .card:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card:not(:first-of-type) .card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card:last-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Example
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul id="example">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cards are available since Bootstrap 4. You can either use the snippets, or you could use the 'well' class in order to get the desired effect. If you use the well class, you will have to do some custom styling.
Link to explanation about wells:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_wells.asp